# Strange definition: indicatrix of tangents of a curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm reading the classical [Manfredo's Differential Geometry book](http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/ggk/do%20Carmo,%20Differential%20Geometry%20of%20Curves%20and%20Surfaces.pdf) and I'm struggling to understand this question on page 22:

[image]

I don't know if I understood what he meant by indicatrix of tangents of a curve. He said we transport the origin of vectors $t(s)$ to the origin of $\mathbb R^2$. The problem is *this is exactly how the coordinates of a vector is defined*. He could simply define the indicatrix $i(s)$ as the coordinates of the tangent vector $t(s)$ viewed as points.

Anyway, following this definition the indicatrix $i$ of tangents of $\alpha$ is defined as $i(s)=t(s)=\alpha'(s)=(x'(s),y'(s),z'(s))$.

Am I right? this question seems a little bit strange for me.

Comment: Yes, this is right, although he's talking about curves in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Author seems to want to give the intuition behind what's going on, your definition is more "cold".